# Why are these buttons with exactly the same classes different widths?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, bulma, tailwind-css

I have two buttons.

[image]

They have exactly the same classes.

[image]

But one is inexplicably wider than the other.

[image]

[image]

All other buttons on the page render full width like the "Declaim" button. There's nothing to the right of these buttons. I have tried refreshing my browser cache and Laravel's view cache. The classes you see are from Tailwind and Bulma and haven't been touched by me other than:

```
.button:active {
    position:relative;
    top:2px;
}
```

What could be happening here?

Update:

In response to Phix and Saqib, yes, it did have a grandparent with flex but I

- Deleted all custom css in app.scss
- Created a demo component with nothing but a container with a div of class "buttons"
- Rendered it alone directly inside main

And incredibly I still have the same problem. Without the div of class "buttons", the buttons are the same size. But I can't work out why "buttons" would be doing this.

Update 2

This is what happens when I set a fixed width:

[image]

Someone probably knows exactly what is wrong looking at that? I unfortunately don't.

Comment: Is the parent container flex?

Comment: according to your screenshots, Claim button is getting some border. Try to look for any border given to the child w.r.t parent container. Also, it would be great if you could recreate a simple demo?

Comment: having the same classes doesn't mean the same style. One may get affect differently by nth-child() for example or `+` selector, etc

Comment: Could you provide more of the code please? Preferably the most minimal, reproducible code possible. Or perhaps a link as well? So that we know what we can work on. Thanks :)

Comment: It looks like margin on the right side, not border. And I would look out for a selector like `button.w-full:first-child` that is applying margin-right on the first element. Try switching your buttons around and you will see margin still on the first one...

Comment: Thanks everyone, still working on this... I have updated the post... by the way the classes are obviously from Bulma not Tailwind.

Comment: Could you just add `margin: auto 0px;` to the class?

Comment: I was assuming w-full would have width: 100% but having a hard time reproducing with that. You really need to share all the CSS you have...

Comment: MrRobboto That's the thing, it still happens when I have zero css apart from the Bulma button classes. However if you are not seeing it, it is clearly something local so I will keep trying to eliminate possible culprits and update this if I figure it out.

Comment: I just checked bulma source and don't even see .w-full in there so that is your class? Please share that...

Comment: Ugh no w-full is Tailwind and button/buttons are Bulma. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: And I do see in Bulma styles like this: `.hero-buttons .button:not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: 1.5rem;
  }` - that seems to be what you're running into or a selector like it... Best to look in DOM inspector at all the styles affecting the element, not just hovering over it like in your screenshot.

Comment: Okay that's helpful thanks

Comment: Thanks everyone.. the solution was to switch to Bulma's full width class (is-fullwidth) instead of using Tailwind's (w-full)

Comment: Please don't add "solved" to the title.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311829/why-cant-i-mark-my-title-as-solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was told not to mark my own question as solved so I am writing the solution I found here.

The problem was mixing Tailwind and Bulma. The solution was using is-fullwidth instead of w-full. Bulma applied a margin that checked for is-fullwidth but obviously had no idea about w-full.

Modifying the "buttons" or "button" classes wasn't working but I know now that I needed to use .buttons:not(:last-child) {}. However, switching to is-fullwidth makes much more sense.

Answer (score 0):

If both buttons have same padding, it might just be the length of the text of the button. "Declaim" is longer than "Claim".

Try adding a fixed width and `box-sizing: border-box;` to include the padding in the width.

Also the default position of a  is `inline-block`. Try making setting it to `block`.

Comment: If I switch the order, the first button still has the problem. By the way, could you have a look at the latest image I show with a fixed width?

Comment: Are you inspecting the first element in your browser to see if there's a :first-child() selector being applied to it?

Comment: Sorry for commenting under my answer and not the thread. There is a margin-right:0.5em to the .buttons .button:not(:last-child):not(.is-fullwidth) selector. Overwrite of get rid of it and it's good.

Comment: Thanks everyone.. the solution was to switch to Bulma's full width class (is-fullwidth) instead of using Tailwind's (w-full)